# How to convert complex HTML <a> tag to ASP .NET MVC 3 ActionLink?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

By design I have

```
<a href="#"><span><strong>ABOUT US</strong></span></a>
```

There is CSS which does some special things with span tag.

But I need to convert it into

```
@Html.ActionLink("ABOUT US", "About", "Home")
```

So I have in some way to put span strong into  @Html.ActionLink

Thank you for any clue!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using the Html.ActionLink helper, I would do it the following way:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("About", "Home")"><span><strong>ABOUT US</strong></span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try create your own custom html helper, here is some clue for you:
[Is it possible to use an ActionLink containing an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990907/is-it-possible-to-use-an-actionlink-containing-an-element)

Hope this help :)

Comment: Hi! Thanks! It's exactly what I've asked! <a href="@Url.Action("Page","Site", new { id = Model.Id, @Type = "test" })">
 <span class="box5">Click anywhere in this box</span> </a>

Answer (score 0):

Use Url.Action to generate only url, not (a) link tag. See the follow link.

http://www.netrostar.com/MVCOutgoingUrls

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, change your css so that any `<a>` tags with a class "strong" have the style you want applied to them.

if your css is like this:

```
strong {
   /* whatever */
}
```

change it to

```
strong, a.strong {
   /* whatever */
}
```

Then you can style up your links just by adding class="strong" like this

`<a href="#" class="strong">ABOUT US<a>`

to get the same style applied to the link.

Then you can acheive the same HTML by going

```
@Html.ActionLink("ABOUT US", "About", "Home", null, new { @class = "strong"} ) ;
```

which will render a link with the class "strong"

Comment: Well... I guessed about this approach but in this case I have to change too much CSS :) Anyway - Thank you!