# Tag <a> in asp.net mvc doesn't work in a project, and is working in the other

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm creating a new ASP.NET website. I've created some before, so I looked at my old code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-controller="Restaurants" asp-route-id="@item.ID">
        <h4 style="white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;">@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.Nom)</h4>
        <img src="~/images/@(nomImage) " alt="image article" />
        <p>Prix : @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.PrixApproximatifPourDeux)$</p>
        <p>Type de cuisine : @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.TypeCuisine.Nom)</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

The URL that ASP.NET creates is this:
https://localhost:44316/Restaurants/Details/3

In my new project, I've written this code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-controller="Produits" asp-route-id="@item.ID">
        <h4 style="white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;">@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.nom)</h4>
        <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.image)" alt="image-produit" />
        <p>Prix : @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.prix)</p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Voir le produit", "Details", "Produits", new { item.ID }, null)
    </a>
</div>
```

The controllers and the views might be different, but the whole code is the same more or less. The only way I'm able to redirect in the new project is by using `Html.ActionLink`, but the user has to click on the text directly, **and my goal is to get the the whole `<div>` to be a link, like in my first project.**

Is there something wrong with my project? Or with my code?

Can I extend the use of `Html.ActionLink` to more than text?

Comment: Your second example nests anchor tags. Examine the rendered html.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the code in the new project isn't working like the code in the old one. If you want to find out, you might have to post the whole new project.

`@Html.ActionLink("Voir le produit", "Details", "Produits", new { item.QuoteID }, null)` creates an entire `<a href=".."></a>` tag, whereas `@Url.Action` just creates a URL, like `Restaurants/Details/3` for example. Good explanation of the difference between `Html.ActionLink` and `Url.Action` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709001/html-actionlink-vs-url-action-in-asp-net-razor).

Try using `Url.Action` instead, like so:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Produits", new { id = item.ID })">
        <h4 style="white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;">@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.nom)</h4>
        <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.image)" alt="image-produit" />
        <p>Prix : @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.prix)</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

You could extend `Html.ActionLink` to include other tags, like the `<h4>` and `<img>` tags in your code, but to do so is [somewhat hacky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7991132/4209895). It seems appropriate here to just use `Url.Action`.